# Different results from using IN and EXISTS

Tags: sql

I have a query that has been giving me fits. Basically I want a left outer join, but without using a join.

I started off using `IN` and got back about 13,000 rows. If I use `EXISTS`, I then get about 11,000 rows. Even if I use `GROUP BY` to make sure duplicates aren't counted, there's still a difference.

Here's some code

This one with exists

```
SELECT upper(EMAIL_ADDRESS)
FROM DATA.CRM_CONTACTS
WHERE EXISTS
  (
  SELECT upper(Email_address)
  FROM DATA.MMBI
  WHERE DATA.CRM_CONTACTS.Email_address = DATA.MMBI.Email_Address
  )
group by 1
order by 1
```

And this is code that uses `IN`:

```
SELECT upper(EMAIL_ADDRESS)
FROM DATA.CRM_CONTACTS
WHERE upper(EMAIL_ADDRESS)  IN
  (
  SELECT upper(Email_address)
  FROM DATA.MMBI
  )
  group by 1
order by 1
```

Is there any reason that would explain why I'm getting different results?

Comment: As an aside, you could also use `SELECT NULL` or `SELECT 1`(which i prefer) in an `EXISTS` or `NOT EXISTS`. Actually nothing is selected, the `SELECT`-part is ignored.

Comment: Apart from that, what are you trying to achieve at all? Your queries will return all rows(apart from `NULL` issues) since you are comparing `EMAIL_ADDRESS` with `EMAIL_ADDRESS`.

Comment: Understand how NULLs affect IN and EXISTS http://www.techrepublic.com/article/oracle-tip-understand-how-nulls-affect-in-and-exists/

Comment: Sorry, must have deleted the `1` that goes with the `group by`. Also edited the code snippet above so that the `exists` statement makes sense

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you're using SQL Server:

In your `in` case, you're making a case-insensitive comparison, uppercasing both values to be compared:

```
WHERE upper(EMAIL_ADDRESS)  IN ( SELECT upper(Email_address)
                                     FROM DATA.MMBI
                                   )
```

In your `exists` case, your join criteria for the correlated subquery is this

```
WHERE DATA.CRM_CONTACTS.Email_address = DATA.MMBI.Email_Address
```

Which means it's going to use the collation in play to make the comparison, which might be case-sensitive.